# CSS float:right goes to next line

Tags: css

This should be simple, but I am misunderstanding CSS behavior.

The searchbar-title-group should occupy a full line and contain a left-justified title and 2 right-justified buttons.  The buttons group is right-justified, but it appears on the next line.  Why?  And how should I fix this?

```css
#searchbar-add-item {
  font-size: 24px;
}

#searchbar-title {
  font-size: x-large;
  visibility: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

#searchbar-title-buttons-group {
  float: right;
}

#searchbar-title-group {
  display: block;
}

#searchbar-toggle-button {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchbar-title-group">
  <span class="" id="searchbar-title">Search Entries.</span>
  <span id="searchbar-title-buttons-group">
   <a href="#" id="searchbar-toggle-button" class="material-icons md-48 md-dark">search</a>
   <a href="/transactions/new" id="searchbar-add-item" class="material-icons md-48 md-dark">add_box</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Edit:  The searchbar-title-group is enclosed by a div with class "container."  Here is the style as shown in the inspector:

```
.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Container is wrapped in body.  Here is body's style per inspector:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Roboto,"Helvetica Neue",Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

The inspector also shows body's style is block (from user agent stylesheet).

The inspector also shows that `.container` inherits a style of block from the user agent stylesheet for `<div>`.  I don't know how that got assigned like that.

Comment: In this day and age of flex and grids, I wouldn't use floats - they weren't meant for what they are being used for anyway

Comment: I tried flex, and it is baffling.  I am certainly open to a solution using a different technique if somebody wants to post one as an answer.

Comment: @cale_b, I tried that, and the buttons are on the 1st line, and the title is on the 2nd.

Comment: That will happen if either one of the `span` elements (so `#searchbar-title` or `#searchbar-title-buttons-group`) have *block* type properties, check for any rules like `display: block` declared to these elements, it looks like they are occupying the full horizontal width and therefore stack below/above each other.

Comment: if you use float:left on searchbar-title does that work? by the way they all appear on the same line for me. Is there something else you're doing?

Comment: I plugged in your code and it works great in latest IE and Chrome and I don't see why it wouldn't work unless there is site-wide css that you didn't include here. Do an f12 on your browser to find if your css is being overridden. The only thing I would change is to use an empty element with the clear:both option after floated elements.  It is cool to learn flex if that's the road you want to take.

Comment: @JonathanChaplin Float left does not work.  When I run the code snippet here in SO, I don't see the title.  I only see the buttons.  I am in most recent Chrome.

Comment: you don't see the title because of visibility:hidden in your #searchbar-title class I tested locally and it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I would use flex

```css
#searchbar-add-item {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.searchbar-title-group {
  width:100%;
  display:flex;                   /* flex */
  flex-direction: row;            /* layout children in a row */
  flex-wrap:nowrap;               /* don't let children wrap */
  justify-content:space-between;  /* add space in between children so whole line is taken */
}

#searchbar-title {
  font-size: x-large;
  white-space: nowrap;
}


#searchbar-toggle-button {
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchbar-title-group">
  <span class="" id="searchbar-title">Search Entries.</span>
  <span id="searchbar-title-buttons-group">
 <a href="#" id="searchbar-toggle-button" class="material-icons md-48 md-dark">search</a>
 <a href="/transactions/new" id="searchbar-add-item" class="material-icons md-48 md-dark">add_box</a>
  </span>
</div>
```

Here are a couple of good sites for learning flex and what it can do:

[Flexbox codepen playground](https://codepen.io/enxaneta/pen/adLPwv)

[Css Tricks - Complete guide to flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

Comment: While I like Flex as a solution, it's fairly complicated / unintuitive, so nice job with your comments! Also, I think it's still relevant to include the disclaimer about variable browser support for flex... and the need (possibly) to use browser-prefixes...

Comment: @cale_b Flex is now supported by all browsers that are being supported by the companies that wrote them.  I don't care for anyone still programming for things like ie8.  If they want to program for unsupported browsers then they can do that themselves

Comment: IE10 and 11 [are buggy](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) and still have fairly large percentage of [market share](https://www.w3counter.com/globalstats.php)

Comment: ie10 is not supported, ie11 works well - the only problem I have with ie11 is that sometimes the defaults are different from other browsers, but that is easily solved.  The main problem is with safari - which doesn't like nested flex boxes but as there aren't any nested flex boxes above I don't have to mention that

Comment: I tried your solution, and the result remains the same.

Comment: @JeffMatthews Then you need to create a [MCVE] as you must have some other styles that are conflicting - as you can see, I have used the html you have provided and it works perfectly

Comment: @Pete, I suspect you are right.  However, when I run your code snippet, like mine above, I don't see the title.  Only the buttons appear on the right.

Comment: @JeffMatthews That's because you have `visibility:hidden` in your styles!

Comment: Fixed it to visible.  No point in using hidden for this example.  I have been using the element inspector to look for overridden styles.  Can the buttons (not the button group) have display = inline inside a flex?  If I don't style them as inline, Google styles them as inline-block.  These are Google's material icons.

Comment: You should be able to have any type of element inside a flex - inline, inline-block or block (I would be weary of flex or inline flex as safari has issues as noted above).  If it is inline block, make sure that your title width is less than 100%.

Comment: @Pete, I edited to provide info on additional enclosing elements, working back to <body>.